# SharePoint WebPart connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint

I'm about to ask a super basic question, but I have googled for hours on end and have yet to find a satisfactory tutorial.

Basically, I just need to access my SQL Server database via a WebPart in SharePoint. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to code my WebPart in Visual C#, but have yet to get anywhere further than the following code:

```
DataSet dataSet = null;

String connectionString = "server=WIN-JAU77JEK513;User ID=WIN-JAU77JEK513/Administrator;Password=;database=db;Connection Timeout=60";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.table;";

conn.Open();
```

And that's all I got. I'm just trying to figure out basic ways of querying and updating the database, nothing fancy or anything. Can someone point me to an easy-to-understand tutorial or post me some snippets of code? I'm completely new to C# programming (having never touched it before two days ago), so I would appreciate it if there are comments or something to help me understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Sharepoint 2010 as well?  Any reason you are going the C# route instead of using the External Content Type feature? This allows you to set up connections to external sql tables and use them in your webparts like they were lists.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=794

Below is a link to a codeproject article that gives a good overview of basic database programming in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Comment: Yeah I do have a reason. The client needs some pretty intense customization and I figure it would be a lot easier to do it with HTML/CSS on my own. Thank you very much for the links, they were really really helpful!

Comment: Same problem here, do you have any solution?